# Wasserstein distance between a distribution and a Dirac mass

Tags: python, histogram, distance

How to measure the Wasserstein distance between an empirical measure and punctual mass (at 0):

[image]

Is this the correct way ?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance

measure = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)

WassDist_measure_dirac = wasserstein_distance(measure,[0]*len(measure))
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Do you run into a problem with this?

Comment: @NickODell No, but I don't know how to check if the answer is correct or not

Comment: This is not a final confirmation, but at least it should be said in your code's favour that it performs correctly on a trivial example: `wasserstein_distance([0], [1]) -> 1.0`, `wasserstein_distance([0, 0], [1, 1]) -> 1.0`, and `wasserstein_distance([0, 0], [1, 1, 1]) -> 1.0` as expected

Answer (score 0):

The Wasserstein distance between two probability measures mu and nu (on the same finite set) is the minimum average distance between two random variables X~mu and Y~nu, where the minimum is taken over all possible such pairs of random variables (X,Y). If nu is a Dirac mass at y then Y is always equal to y. Thus the Wasserstein distance is the average (the expectation) of d(X, y), the distance between X and y. The distance d is the one defining the "costs", I don't know how it is inputed with **scipy**.

To conclude, if mu and nu are distributed on the (finite) set E then the Wasserstein distance is the sum of the  mu(x)*d(x,y)  for x running over E.